# Doctrine second level cache fatal error without @cache on entity

Tags: caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine, second-level-cache

I have a strange Doctrine behaviour.
Classes:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Cache
 */
class UserInfo {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @Cache
     * @OneToOne
     */
    protected $extra;
    public function getExtra(){
        return $this->extra;
    }
}
/*!! Without @Cache ANNOTATION on ExtraUserInfo !!*/
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class ExtraUserInfo {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OnToOne
     */
    protected $info;
    /**
     * @Column
     */
    protected $extra;
}
```

Doctrine causes a fatal error when i do:

```
$userinf->getExtra();
```

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister::getCacheRegion() in /lib/Doctrine/ORM/Cache/DefaultEntityHydrator.php on line 137
This happens because `$assocPersister` is instance of BasicEntityPersister.

It is a Doctrine bug, or i have to specify `@Cache` on all entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed here https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/7e5a1c6b0d928a63626fea961dd4cecb74ab01de.
So, the problem does not exists any-more.